# Must the Map be defined again and again?

Tags: android, simpleadapter

I was intended to load datas from databases to ListView with SimpleAdapter, just as:

```
private void loadData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor cursor = mHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "select * from dict", null);
        int wordIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("word");
        int detailIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("detail");
        int flagIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("flag");
        **(1)**//Map<String,String>map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        //map defined here, items are all the last record

        for (cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast();cursor.moveToNext()){
            **(2)**Map<String,String>map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            if(cursor.getString(wordIndex)==null) break;
//          Log.d(tag,"word: "+cursor.getString(wordIndex));
            map.put("word", cursor.getString(wordIndex));
//          Log.d(tag,"detail: "+cursor.getString(detailIndex));
            map.put("detail", cursor.getString(detailIndex));   
//          Log.d(tag,"flag: "+cursor.getString(flagIndex));
            map.put("flag", cursor.getString(flagIndex));
            listItems.add(map);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

listItems is defined as `ArrayList<Map<String, String>> listItems;`

when I defined the Map as **1**, where the map is outside the for cycle, listItems keep listItems.length records of the final one, while the map is defined as **2**, listItems keep listItems.length record as the database.
Could someone just tell why? I will appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this the second way i.e **2** .

The reason is in each iteration a **new** object of `Map<String,String>` type is created and hence a fresh item is added to your `ArrayList` in each iteration when you use way **2**.

But in the first way, i.e. **1** in each iteration no new object is created as it was done only once before the **for** loop.And hence you don't get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

what `listItems.add()` add is a `Map<String,String>` object, and the content of Map
will be changed in each loop as way 1. And listItems just Add `listItems.length` times the same Map object